# VNC viewer : Timed out waiting for response from computer

Tags: vnc-viewer

I am entering the ip of the machine I wanted to connect using **[vnc](https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/viewer/)** viewer but it's giving me this error:

[image: vnc-viewer]

Answer (score 0):

So, that error means

> No response was received from the specified IP address, even to reject
> the connection.

Ways to fix this:

```
Check the remote computer is switched on. Ensure antivirus software lists VNC Server as an exception, and the firewall is configured to allow access on VNC Server’s listening port (5900 by default).

See  if you are attempting to establish a direct connection over the Internet.
```

You can check any vnc error message from https://help.realvnc.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002254738-VNC-Connect-Error-Messages